# Correct way to include Stripe library inside react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, stripe-payments, stripe.js

I need to use a lot of the functions of Stripe API in my app, not only checkout which is provided by https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout

For example, I need to edit customers, subscriptions, cancel them, etc...

So what is the best way to access those functions ?

For example I want to create a customer like that:

```
Stripe.apiKey = stripeKey;

let params = {};
params.put("email", "jenny.rosen@example.com");
params.put("source", "src_18eYalAHEMiOZZp1l9ZTjSU0");
let customer = Customer.create(params);
```

but how do I import stripe library correctly into my projetct ? I tried adding the script to `<head>` on my index.html. Also tried to add it dynamically inside `componentDidMount()` like this:

```
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://js.stripe.com/v3/";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

What is the best way to add a custom JS library to react project ? Should I do it via Webpack and how please?

Comment: What about [`this`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)?

Comment: [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) is a frontend library, its only purpose is to collect and tokenize payment information. All other operations with Stripe's API (creating a customer, a charge, etc.) must be done server-side.